# FTP Client Output Response standard

Tags: ftp, sftp, ftp-client

After successful FTP file transfer, the the response is used to be "`226 File send OK`", but suddenly, it has changed to be "`226 Transfer complete`"

I have below questions:

1. Does FTP response code has any standard?
2. Can we customize FTP output response for a specific status code?

Find the standard FTP response for file transfer

```
$ ftp canopus
Connected to canopus.austin.century.com.
220 canopus.austin.century.com FTP server (Version 4.1 Sat Nov 23 12:52:09 CST 1991) ready.
Name (canopus:eric): dee
331 Password required for dee.
Password:
230 User dee logged in.
ftp> pwd
257 "/home/dee" is current directory.
ftp> cd desktop
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> type ascii
200 Type set to A.
ftp> send typescript
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening data connection for typescript (128.114.4.99,1412).
226 File send OK.
ftp> cdup
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
```

Note: suddenly the response text `226 File send OK` has changed to `226 Transfer complete`

Find the details about FTP responses on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 959,    4.2.  FTP REPLIES](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#page-35):

> An FTP reply consists of a three digit number (transmitted as
> three alphanumeric characters) followed by some text.  **The number
> is intended for use by automata to determine what state to enter
> next; the text is intended for the human user.**  It is intended
> that the three digits contain enough encoded information that the
> user-process (the User-PI) will not need to examine the text and
> may either discard it or pass it on to the user, as appropriate.
> In particular, the text may be server-dependent, so there are
> likely to be varying texts for each reply code.